# Why do I get different results when I run the same program in pycharm and IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I want run another python file in my code.It's simple:

```
import os

command = "python3 简易时钟.py"
os.system(command)
```

When I use Pycharm, it will run normally.
When I use IDLE, nothing happened. Why?
macOS 10.15.7
python 3.7.9

Comment: You might want to try with a more regular filename for your other script, just in case...

Answer (score 0):

This works in idle(Windows) for me. Try using the exact path of the file.

Like

```
command = r"C:\Users\(your_username)\Documents\python3 简易时钟.py"
```

or whatever the path of the file is.

Or if the python3 简易时钟.py file doesn't generate any output file the python3 简易时钟.py file will run and get closed in the background once it is completed execution.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. The 简易时钟.py will open a tkinter window.